# Rotate webcam video in empathy

Tags: video, webcam

I have a Lenovo x220 Tablet laptop with a built-in webcam, which is shown by `lsusb` as a `Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd` device (device id 04f2:b217). The `uvcvideo` kernel module is used as a driver for it.

The webcam is working out-of-the-box under Ubuntu 12.04 (very nice!), but the video is upside-down (for example in Empathy and when I open `/dev/video0` with vlc).
So how can I rotate the webcam video by 180° degrees? I would prefer an application-independent solution, because for example Empathy seems to have no settings for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[WebcamStudio](http://www.ws4gl.org/)** in order to manage your webcam orientation and change or enrich your webcam experience with some extra features such as:

1. Integrating animations and/or text layers to your video stream.
2. Use a pre-recorded fixed image/gif animation/video for broadcasting
   over your preferred video conferencing system.
3. Use several sources in the same session, switching from a device to
   another just in a click.

A screenshot from the web is placed here for your convenience:

[image]

Basically, what Webcam Studio does is to provide your system with a virtual "bridge" between your physical webcam and what the video conference software is expecting to find, thus the ability to enrich the streamed video with effects/filters/animations/etc.

Good luck!

P.S. Usage of the webcam studio software can be combined with Empathy/Skype/Google+ Hangouts and other flash based video conferencing web services.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, running a Java program and adding a kernel module seems to be quite over-engineered for something like this. Is there perhaps a simpler solution?

Comment: Did you already see this? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=838210